# Resize image generated by BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()

Tags: android, image-resizing, bitmapfactory

I am creating audio player,I want to show the song cover to the player,  it working with small image but if the mp3 file have large image then it goes out of layout view. I'm re-sizing image to 300x300 by using below code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inDensity = 300;
opt.inTargetDensity = 300;

songCoverView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(songCover, 0, songCover.length, opt));
```

But it still shows larger and goes out of layout.

Whats wrong with this code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap)

`bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(songCover, 300, 300, true);`

And you can keep the same aspect ratio for the old image... I use the following logic:

```
        int width  = songCover.getWidth();
        int height = songCover.getHeight();
        float scaleHeight = (float)height/(float)300;
        float scaleWidth  = (float)width /(float)300;
        if (scaleWidth < scaleHeight) scale = scaleHeight;
        else                          scale = scaleWidth;

        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(songCover, (int)(width/scale), (int)(height/scale), true);
```

Comment: but, The image looks like forced to that pixels if image scale is not 1:1. For sample, like <img> in html have max-width and max-height.

Comment: @MuhammadResnaRizkiPratama, I have added an example to the answer to show you how to keep the old aspect ratio.

Answer (score 8):

Turns out that there's a bug in Android: decodeByteArray somehow ignores some input options. A known workaround is using decodeStream with input array wrapped into ByteArrayInputStream instead, like this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inDensity = 300;
opt.inTargetDensity = 300;

songCoverView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(songConver), null, opt));
```

Comment: Code example was actually using decodeByteArray – that was my mistake, obviously. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the property the Bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, (int)x, (int)y, true);
```